# Writing an addin for NUnit integration in VS 2005 IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2005, nunit

I'm starting to write an add-in for Visual Studio 2005 that would integrate NUnit with the IDE. Any ideas on how and where I should start? I have a basic idea on how add-ins work.

I believe I would need to know the NUnit API for this type of integration. Where can I find enough resources to achieve this?

Comment: Are you interested in using such plugin, or merely in learning something while writing it? If it's the former, try TestDriven.NET.

Comment: Right now, it's just for learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some resources you might try:

1. [Monodevelop](http://monodevelop.com/Main_Page) has NUnit addin. You can read a lot about how to communicate with NUnit API by reading the [source](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/monodevelop/main/src/addins/NUnit/), especially if it is more for learning purposes.
2. The NUnit GUI is open source, so you can see how it interacts with the NUnit runner, etc. It's just a wrapper, and should contain all the functionality you will need.
3. The guys at [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) are very responsive, and if you subscribe to their [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/nunit-discuss) they'll help you a lot about finding the appropriate APIs.
4. There are a lot of articles about how to create addins for VS, here is [one](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/satisharveti/VSAdd-ins03022009064839AM/VSAdd-ins.aspx) (you can find more with google).

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the Visual nUnit for VS 2008 project - its open source and integrates well with VS 2008- http://www.bubblecloud.org/visualnunit

Answer (score 0):

I want to add a plug for MBUnit which I think is pretty much a superset of nUnit features. The [api doc](http://www.gallio.org/api/html/index.html) looks good.